# how to disable breakpoints when debugging go program in dlv(delve) like using gdb?

Tags: debugging, go, delve

When using gdb to debugging go program, we can disable all breakpoints by using 'disable' command, and then we can 'enable' breakpoints if we need. But when using dlv(delve), i'm not found command like 'disable' in gdb, I can only use 'clear' or 'clearall' command to delete breakpoints, but I need recreating breakpoints if I need using these breakpoints again.
My questing is if there any command exist in dlv can 'disable' breakpoints and then I can re-enable them?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no way to do this AFAIK; not with the standard commandline anyway.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker Thank you for your answer. As a new delve user, I'm interesting to known why 'disable'-like command not support in dlv? In my mind,  this is a very useful command when debugging.Or there is any other better meth to disable-enable breakpoints?

Comment: Probably because no one took the time to make it (yet). I agree it would be a useful feature though; it's actually on my wishlist as well. I suspect it wouldn't be too hard to implement. So if you really want it, you could try implementing it :-)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I found jetBrain's GoLand debug-ui support 'disable breakpoints' feature today, and it works.  I known GoLand use  delve as its debug tools, maybe jetBrain do something above delve.

Comment: It's just an UI to the Delve API, like the commandline interface is. It can implement feature independently.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I running my program in delve and open remote-debug port, then GoLand link to delve server to debugging, so I think GoLand implement some feature in its debug client.